# A Simple Subtraction, Three Answers

Tags: lateral-thinking

Think laterally and you will get three answers to a simple question.

The question is:

> What do you get if you minus Ten from Forty Nine?

The answers are

> 39
>
> 41
>
> 59

How? Please explain.
No partial answers.

Comment: What is this, a [tag:lateral-thinking] puzzle with "silly maths", and it's actually quite decent? What's next, a [tag:mystery]  puzzle with a satisfying solution?

Comment: Hmmm. Here is a mystery puzzle @Bass. Inspector Jacques Clouseau is  called upon urgently to investigate a homicide at a Convention in Paris.The Speaker was murdered and all doors to the speech room were closed. Who did it? Hint: It was a Butler's convention :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get any of the answers using

> Roman numerals: XLIX = 49, remove the first X, leaves LIX = 59. Or remove the last, to get XLI = 41. Or correctly do the subtraction, to get XXXIX = 39.